# How to disable trackpad acceleration on M1 MBPs just like on Intel MBPs?

Tags: macos, trackpad, apple-silicon

I've got a new M1 Pro MBP and I am struggling to get the trackpad into a usable state.

`com.apple.trackpad.scaling` on 0 or -1 don't have acceleration but they're way too slow. This wasn't the case on my Intel MBP where -1 was reasonably fast.

How can I disable trackpad acceleration on an 16" M1 Pro MBP running macOS 12.2 such that it roughly matches the experience on an Intel MBP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now possible to accomplish this with https://linearmouse.org/ 0.7

They have added per device settings, and this means you can change configuration for trackpad acceleration as well.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I have found is [CursorSense](https://plentycom.jp/en/cursorsense/index.html) where you can simply disable acceleration with a checkbox to get what feels just like the trackpad on an Intel mac to me. (Acceleration of 0 with Sensitivity of 1904 is equivalent to this setting.)

The app is proprietary and paid (10$) unfortunately.

Comment: Linear mouse (free and open source) can accomplish this since latest release. https://linearmouse.org/

Comment: I've switched over too, more info at https://github.com/linearmouse/linearmouse/issues/65

Answer (score -2):

If you’re not sure which utility you want for this, go for a Setapp trial.

- https://setapp.com/how-to/how-to-use-bettertouchtool

It has [BTT which is my value and functionality gold standard for this sort of task](https://folivora.ai/). I prefer the new curve tbh, but I get some people want the old implementation and have very good reasons for not changing. The author offers a 45 day free trial as well if you’re only interested in using BTT to change the sensitivity of the trackpad.

- https://folivora.ai/

Comment: What do you mean by 'new curve'? I don't want any curve whatsoever, I want a straight line.

Comment: Does BTT even facilitate flattening the acceleration curve? It seems to be a utility for an entirely different purpose.

Comment: Yes, I linked to the direct download page. You want to change what BTT calls sensitivity